# Automated function script

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 4 functions for buttons and relative div. Basically, when we click on button it should hide some div and show a single div. It should change the background of that button, "on hover mouse" over the button should change the property of button.

Now I want to make it automated, meaning it should automatically perform the click events one by one. I have tried many things without success. My functions are as following:

```
function Fun1() {
    $("#BtnItem1").addClass("ButtonsSliderHover1");
    $("#BtnItem2").addClass("ButtonsSliderNormal");
    $("#BtnItem3").addClass("ButtonsSliderNormal");
    $("#BtnItem4").addClass("ButtonsSliderNormal");

    $("#BtnItem2").removeClass("ButtonsSliderHover1");
    $("#BtnItem3").removeClass("ButtonsSliderHover1");
    $("#BtnItem4").removeClass("ButtonsSliderHover1");

    $("#Item1").css('display', 'block');
    $("#Item2").css('display', 'none');
    $("#Item3").css('display', 'none');
    $("#Item4").css('display', 'none');

}
function Fun2() {
    $("#BtnItem1").addClass("ButtonsSliderNormal");
    $("#BtnItem2").addClass("ButtonsSliderHover1");
    $("#BtnItem3").addClass("ButtonsSliderNormal");
    $("#BtnItem4").addClass("ButtonsSliderNormal");

    $("#BtnItem1").removeClass("ButtonsSliderHover");
    $("#BtnItem1").removeClass("ButtonsSliderHover1");
    $("#BtnItem3").removeClass("ButtonsSliderHover1");
    $("#BtnItem4").removeClass("ButtonsSliderHover1");

    $("#Item1").css('display', 'none');
    $("#Item2").css('display', 'block');
    $("#Item3").css('display', 'none');
    $("#Item4").css('display', 'none');
}
function Fun3() {
    $("#BtnItem1").addClass("ButtonsSliderNormal");
    $("#BtnItem2").addClass("ButtonsSliderNormal");
    $("#BtnItem3").addClass("ButtonsSliderHover1");
    $("#BtnItem4").addClass("ButtonsSliderNormal");

    $("#BtnItem1").removeClass("ButtonsSliderHover");
    $("#BtnItem1").removeClass("ButtonsSliderHover1");
    $("#BtnItem2").removeClass("ButtonsSliderHover1");
    $("#BtnItem4").removeClass("ButtonsSliderHover1");

    $("#Item1").css('display', 'none');
    $("#Item2").css('display', 'none');
    $("#Item3").css('display', 'block');
    $("#Item4").css('display', 'none');
}
function Fun4() {
    $("#BtnItem1").addClass("ButtonsSliderNormal");
    $("#BtnItem2").addClass("ButtonsSliderNormal");
    $("#BtnItem3").addClass("ButtonsSliderNormal");
    $("#BtnItem4").addClass("ButtonsSliderHover1");

    $("#BtnItem1").removeClass("ButtonsSliderHover");
    $("#BtnItem1").removeClass("ButtonsSliderHover1");
    $("#BtnItem2").removeClass("ButtonsSliderHover1");
    $("#BtnItem3").removeClass("ButtonsSliderHover1");

    $("#Item1").css('display', 'none');
    $("#Item2").css('display', 'none');
    $("#Item3").css('display', 'none');
    $("#Item4").css('display', 'block');
}
```

Comment: can you post a screen shot of your UI ?

Comment: On page load you want to perform click event ? if yes than what will be time interval to perform this operation?

Comment: http://imagesup.net/?di=16136747605116 here is my image ...

Comment: @Roopendra ! i want on page load its calls Fun1 after 5sec it will call Fun2 and then after 5 sec it will call Fun3 in the iend it will  call Fun4 after 5 sec

Comment: Your code is very repetitive. You could probably clean it up a lot using classes instead of IDs. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VBVmF/).

Comment: @David  : absolutely right. you can do same thing by one function. check click event on class and get id of link by `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: Instead of using `$("#Item1").css('display', 'none');` why not just `$("#Item1").hide();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, you would be able to set an interval that calls the different functions like so:

```
var actions = [Fun1, Fun2, Fun3, Fun4];
var index = 0;

function cycle() {
    if(++index == actions.length) index = 0;
    actions[index]();
}

window.setInterval(cycle, 5000);
```

But as I mention in comments, you could probably reduce your code to just one single comment, passing a variable, and in that case your interval could look like this:

```
var index = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {
    if(++index > 4) index = 1;
    Fun(index);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: thanks a lot you are great ... I was stuck on this problem from last 3 hours ....... i am new in jquery  so